Rails 7 - How do I display images that are in a different location than my Rails app?
My Rails app resides in /Users/adam/railsapps/my_project.
The images are stored in /Users/adam/gallery/.
In the database of my Rails app, I have stored information about the images, including the path to them.
In my Rails app, when I do
[![<%= image_tag("/Users/adam/gallery/#{image.filename_path}") %>][1]][1]

the images are now displayed. Note - the path to the images in the example above is correct.
When I check the logs, I see there the following:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Users/adam/gallery/img_name.jpg"

I also tried this:
<img src="/Users/adam/gallery/<%= image.filename_path %>">

with no luck.
How do I solve this problem?

Note: This is on my dev environment. For production, I plan the images to be stored on one server/service and the Rails app fetching and displaying them on another server.

Web browsers do not let you link directly to images on the local file system. That would be very insecure. Instead you need to serve the images with a web server. There are plenty of options for simple web servers (OS-X even has one built in) for static files.

I see. I am having one application that's generating these images, and then I have the second app, which is the Rails app, that will work with them (display them). What's the best approach here?

That's largely a matter of opinion. You could for example symlink the directory to the /public directory in your Rails application to have it serve the files.

It seems that the problem is that the rails router is trying to find the path you added. however isn't an internal rails path.So, probably you have to add file:/// at the beginning of the url in order take it as an absolute url within your file system
<%= image_tag("file:///Users/adam/gallery/#{image.filename_path}") %>

on the other hand, I think it's a bit weird that you are trying to open a file which is outside of your project, So once the project is deployed it won't be able to serve the images, I would recommend you to store the images in the assets folder of your project or
use other services like AWS S3 to store the images

Most browsers (all?) will only allow assets to be loaded from file:// sources when the page is loaded via file:// and not http or https. So while this might work for a simple static page it's not a solution for a Rails app even in development.

I agree, That's why I recommended change the current file location or use other alternative
